# Evaluation of $\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{\sigma_0-i\infty}^{\sigma_0+i\infty}\frac{ e^{st}}{s\sin(s)}ds$

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

where $\sigma_0>0$, and $t>0$. Anyone has a clue about how to evaluate the inverse Laplace transform?

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem ? And you mean $\sigma_0\not \in \pi \Bbb{Z}$, the result depends on which interval you take it. For $t >0, \frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{\sigma_0-i\infty}^{\sigma_0+i\infty}\frac{ e^{st}}{s\sin(s)}ds=\sum_{\pi n < \sigma_0} Res(\frac{ e^{st}}{s\sin(s)},\pi n)$

Comment: Yes. I know the residue theorem. $\sigma_0>0$ and the result should be an infinite sum. However, I am not sure the exact form. So I asked this question.

Comment: Got it. Thanks you.

Comment: $Res(\frac{ e^{st}}{s\sin(s)},0) = t$, for $n\ne 0$, $Res(\frac{ e^{st}}{s\sin(s)},\pi n)= (-1)^n \frac{e^{t\pi n}}{\pi n}$.

Comment: I have another question: what if the $sin(s)$ is replaced by $tan(s)$? Will the result change?

Comment: Yes the residue won't be the same. $Res(f(s),a)$ is the coefficient of $(s-a)^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion of $f(s)$ at $s=a$. It is equal to $\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{|s-a|=\epsilon} f(s)ds$ ($f$ is assumed to be meromorphic)